# Invert match in sed to print all lines until line break

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to print the inverse match (inverse match pattern will be in first line and in end of word in my paragraph)  in a paragraph until a line break.

Tried with `sed` using `[^text]` not working.

My pattern string will be at the end of word `xxx_yyyy: ZZZ`.

`sed -n '/[^ZZZ]$/,/^$/p'` not working.

Can some one correct me what wrong here.

Input:

```
sometext tobe here xxx_yyyy: ZZZ
sjhdajsh 
skdjah
hjk 

sometext tobe here xxx_yyyy: AAA 
sjhdajsh 
skdjah 
hjk 

sometext tobe here xxx_yyyy: ZZZ
sjhdajsh
skdjah 
hjk
```

Desired output:

needs to print the paragraph  not contain `xxx_yyyy: ZZZ`

```
sometext tobe here xxx_yyyy: AAA
sjhdajsh 
skdjah 
hjk
```

Comment: `[^text]` matches any character that is not `t` or `e` or `x` or `t` - you probably want `sed -n '/ZZZ$/,/^$/!p'` or `sed '/ZZZ$/,/^$/d'` (delete lines that ARE in the addressed range)

Comment: @Renga do you realise what steeldriver told you? Your `[^ZZZ]` pattern is not "_match anything except ZZZ, at the start of line_", it's "_match any_ one character _that isn't Z (and isn't Z and isn't Z), anywhere in the line_"

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier to do with `awk` than with `sed`:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -F '\n' '!($1 ~ /ZZZ$/)' file
sometext tobe here xxx_yyyy: AAA
sjhdajsh
skdjah
hjk
```

This first sets the record separator, `RS`, to the empty string.  With this special value of `RS`, `awk` will treat each paragraph, delimited by one or more empty line, as a record.  With `-F '\n'` we tell `awk` to treat each line of the paragraph as a field.

The test `!($1 ~ /ZZZ$/)` will be true for each record (paragraph) whose first field (1st line) does *not* end with the string `ZZZ`.  Each such paragraph will be printed.

If you want an empty line after each outputted section, add `-v ORS='\n\n'` to the `awk` command line (before the `awk` code).

---

With `sed`, you could possibly do

```
$ sed '/ZZZ$/,/^$/d' file
sometext tobe here xxx_yyyy: AAA
sjhdajsh
skdjah
hjk
```

I.e., "delete all lines between any line ending with `ZZZ` to the next empty line".  You could also use the `sed` expression `/ZZZ$/,/^$/!p` with `sed -n`.  Note however that an `ZZZ` on any *other* line other than the first line of a paragraph would also trigger this deletion.

This issue could obviously be fixed (by reading paragraphs, line by line, into the hold space, and then deciding which ones to print and which ones to discard), but it would turn into more of a bother than just using the `awk` variation above.

---

Just to comment on the expression `[^ZZZ]` that you use in the question.  This is exactly equivalent to `[^Z]` and will match any single character that is not a `Z`.  Likewise, `[^text]` is the same as `[^etx]` and would match any single character that is not an `e`, `t`, or `x`.